# Trying to emulate a live communication from a micro device usign tty0tty and trying to read data using Pyserial

Tags: python, ubuntu, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to read data from a device and write the data to a file. But I don't have the device with me so I'm trying to emulate the device and then go forward with developing the application further.

I used tty0tty to open 2 virtual ports /dev/tnt0 and /dev/tnt1 to open 2 serial ports and used the following code to emulate a device sending live data and writing the data from the port to a file.

```
import serial

# Define the virtual serial port names
port_send = "/dev/tnt2"
port_receive = "/dev/tnt3"


ser_send = serial.Serial(
    port_send,
    9600,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    timeout=3
    )

ser_receive = serial.Serial(
    port_receive,
    9600,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    timeout=3
    )

time.sleep(1)

try:
    counter = 0
    with open("received_data.txt", "a") as file:
        while True:

            # Data to send (simulating live data)
            data_to_send = "Live data: " + str(counter) + "\r\n"
            counter += 1

            # Send data to the virtual device
            ser_send.write(data_to_send.encode())
            ser_send.flush()  

            time.sleep(0.1)

            received_data = ser_receive.read().decode().strip()
            print(f"Received data: '{received_data}' (readline() result: '{ser_receive.readline()}')")
            if received_data:
                
                file.write(received_data + "\n")
            file.flush()  

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An Error has occoured: {e}")
    ser_send.close()
    ser_receive.close()
```

`Received data: '' (readline() result: 'b''')`

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.03
Python: 3.10.12

These are the things I tried:

1. Using socat instead of tty0tty and it gave the same result.
2. Different timeout and baudrate values.
3. Tried entering data manually to tnt0 it sometimes write to the file but mostly it shows the error:
   `device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)`

EDIT:
Changed tnt0 and 1 to tnt2 and tnt3 and the code works now, but when I try to separate the sender and receiver into separate files `device reports readiness to read but returns no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)` e pops up. I guess I'm reading and writing to the port at the same time but is there any way to solve this?

SOLVED: It was my mistake having the minicom terminal open at the same time(Oops)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.